# How do I send Information into a TWiml Redirect Widget in Studio and How is Liquid Variable Input Method used?

Tags: twilio-studio

I have Json values that I would like to send into a **TwiML Redirect** widget.
The Json comes from an HTTP Request.
I see that besides the Methods Get and Post, there is an additional Method for **Liquid Variable Input**, could this be my solution?
If it is, how does it work? I have had no luck setting this option up.

My Json from (GetAccountsByPhoneNumber):

```
{"Accounts": [
      {"AccountNumber": "9999999998", "HouseNumber": "3207", "StreetName": "Stokesberry ln"},
      {"AccountNumber": "9999999997", "HouseNumber": "1204", "StreetName": "S Hardneir Rd"},
      {"AccountNumber": "9999999996", "HouseNumber": "533", "StreetName": "Park Street"},
      {"AccountNumber": "9999999995", "HouseNumber": "926", "StreetName": "S CO RD 67"}
]}
```

The Twiml Function Prompts to pick which account they are calling about.

```
    exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
        const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
//This is Where I need to get Access to my JSON Object, 
//it works with Function, but does not return to studio flow.
        var responseMany = JSON.parse(event.IncomingJson);
        var gather = twiml.gather({
            input: 'dtmf speech',
            timeout: 5,
            hints: '1,2,3,4,5,9',
            numDigits: 1
        });
        gather.say("If you are calling about ");
        gather.say({voice: 'Polly.Joanna'}).ssmlSayAs({'interpret-as': 'address'}, responseMany.Accounts[0].HouseNumber + " " + responseMany.Accounts[0].StreetName);
        gather.say("Press or say one.");

        gather.say("If you are calling about ");
        gather.say({voice: 'Polly.Joanna'}).ssmlSayAs({'interpret-as': 'address'}, responseMany.Accounts[1].HouseNumber + " " + responseMany.Accounts[1].StreetName);
        gather.say("Press or say two.");

        if(responseMany.Accounts.length >= 3){
            gather.say("If you are calling about ");
            gather.say({voice: 'Polly.Joanna'}).ssmlSayAs({'interpret-as': 'address'}, responseMany.Accounts[2].HouseNumber + " " + responseMany.Accounts[2].StreetName);
            gather.say("Press or say three.");
        }
          if(responseMany.Accounts.length >= 4){
            gather.say("If you are calling about ");
            gather.say({voice: 'Polly.Joanna'}).ssmlSayAs({'interpret-as': 'address'}, responseMany.Accounts[3].HouseNumber + " " + responseMany.Accounts[3].StreetName);
            gather.say("Press or say four.");
        }  
      twiml.redirect("https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/.../Flows/...?FlowEvent=return")
        callback(null, twiml);
    };
```

As a function it crashes on the **twiml.redirect** and never re-enters the flow.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems here.

First, the Liquid Variable Input option for Method is just a way to pass in your choice of `GET` or `POST` at runtime. To send data in and out of a TwiML Redirect widget, you have to exclusively use GET parameters appended to URL strings.

This isn't ideal for a complex JSON document, particularly because a URI can have a shorter size limit than an HTTP body, but assuming your data passing needs aren't that extreme, you could accomplish this by sending the HTTP Request response in its serialized (unparsed) form directly into the function as a get parameter. Twilio should take care of the URL encoding. Your TwiML Redirect widget configuration should look something like this:

```
Method: GET
URL: https://example.twil.io/func?IncomingJson={{widgets.HTML_REQUEST_WIDGET_NAME.body}}
```

Your other problem is that you aren't handling the response from your `<Gather>` verb. Gather will append a `Digits` property to whatever request it sends to the `action` attribute's URL, which by default is the same URL that originated the TwiML document. You *might* be able to do all of this in one call (and avoid the need for the `twiml.redirect` entirely) by doing something like this:

```js
const gather = twiml.gather({
    input: 'dtmf speech',
    timeout: 5,
    hints: '1,2,3,4,5,9',
    numDigits: 1,
    method: 'GET',
    action: context.FLOW_WEBHOOK_URL + '?FlowEvent=return'
    // Use an environment variable for the Webhook URL
});
```

When Twilio triggers the action URL, it will append `&Digits=1` (for example) to the URL, which will then be accessible back in your flow as a liquid variable: `{{widgets.TWIML_REDIRECT_WIDGET_NAME.Digits}}`.